# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(an+b)$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is it valid to say that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(an+b)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\cos(an)\cos b-\sin(an)\sin b)=\cos b\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(an)-\sin b\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(an) ?
$$
(Although $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(an)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(an)$ diverge.)

If not, then how to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(an+b)$ is bounded?

Comment: The series is divergent when $a=b=0$.

Comment: $\sum _{n=1}^m \cos (a n+b)=\csc \left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{a m}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} (a m+a+2 b)\right)$. You can see what happens when $a$ is close to $2k\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos(an+b) = Re(e^{ib}(e^{ai})^n)$. Add the geometric series, and you will realize that its sum is bounded (assuming that $a\neq 2k\pi$, otherwise the quotient is 1).

Comment: But why can we use the geometric series if $|e^{ai}|=1$? $|e^{ai}|$ should be less than one in order to apply the geometric series, shouldn't it?

Comment: No. Simply substitute into the formula that comuptes the sum of the first $n$ elements in a geometric series, and you will find that the only problematic case is $e^{ai}=1$, rather than $|e^{ai}|=1$.